# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable opencv-python / python face_recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, webcam, face-recognition

I have face_recognition python script, and running fine if executed, but it randomly show error if execute:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "faces_test.py", line 38, in <module>
      rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

That error show randomly sometimes running sometimes got that error. I don't understand what's happen, but I change face_recognition tolerance at api.py from 0.6 to 0.4 before. I'm not sure that chage make random error to opencv

I want to running my script and don't get any random error like that, any solution?

environment version:

- python = 3.8.2
- opencv-contrib-python               4.2.0.32
- opencv-python                       4.2.0.32
- face-recognition                    1.3.0
- face-recognition-models    0.3.0

My python script:

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np

# This is a super simple (but slow) example of running face recognition on live video from your webcam.
# There's a second example that's a little more complicated but runs faster.

# PLEASE NOTE: This example requires OpenCV (the `cv2` library) to be installed only to read from your webcam.
# OpenCV is *not* required to use the face_recognition library. It's only required if you want to run this
# specific demo. If you have trouble installing it, try any of the other demos that don't require it instead.

# Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

# Load a sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
obama_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("./training/obama.jpg")
obama_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_image)[0]

# Load a second sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
biden_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("./training/biden.jpg")
biden_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(biden_image)[0]

# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    obama_face_encoding,
    biden_face_encoding
]
known_face_names = [
    "obama",
    "biden"
]

while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

    # Find all the faces and face enqcodings in the frame of video
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    # Loop through each face in this frame of video
    for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
        # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

        name = "Unknown"

        # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
        # if True in matches:
        #     first_match_index = matches.index(True)
        #     name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

        # Or instead, use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
        face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        #print(face_distances)
        #print(best_match_index)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
            print(name)

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The error message says that `video_capture.read()` returned `None`. You have to find out why.

Answer (score 3):

sorry for the late response, but if you're still working through coding with OpenCV maybe this will help.

**First Comment**

You are probably not getting any video coming through the webcam feed.

For example, look at this section of code

```
# Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

Sometimes the camera will initialize in slot '1' instead of '0'. Its important to take into consideration that these initializations can bounce around. If you want to ensure that the camera is being recognized correctly, you can always explicitly define your camera location in a variable and also do some error handling.

**Example for problem one:**

```
def setup_camera():
    """
    Initialize camera by calling cv2.VideoCapture
    Produces a variable that you can read from using self.capture.read
    If camera doesn't connect prints error and Camera not conntected
    """

    device = '/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-HD_Camera_Manufacturer_USB_2.0_Camera-video-index0'

    try:
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(device)
        print("Camera Connection Successful")
        self.capture.release()
    except IOError as e:
        print(e)
        print("Camera Not Connected")
```

This will at least get you started and will tell you if the camera feed is not recording.

If you want to be able to find Cameras easily on your system (and you're using linux - I'm an ubuntu guy so sorry if you are windows) you can run a simple package like v4l-utils to track down the cameras. Something like the following code:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

Should give you a response like the following:

```
USB 2.0 Camera: HD USB Camera (usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5):
    /dev/video0
```

You can then run a command with udevadm to get more info on the **/dev/video0**:

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/video0
```

Which will return something like the following:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/video4linux/video0
N: video0
S: v4l/by-id/usb-HD_Camera_Manufacturer_USB_2.0_Camera-video-index0
S: v4l/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.5:1.0-video-index0
E: COLORD_DEVICE=1
E: COLORD_KIND=camera
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/v4l/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.5:1.0-video-index0 /dev/v4l/by-id/usb-HD_Camera_Manufacturer_USB_2.0_Camera-video-index0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/video0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/video4linux/video0
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=video4linux-pci-0000_00_1a_0-usb-0_1_5_1_0
E: ID_MODEL=USB_2.0_Camera
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x202.0\x20Camera
E: ID_MODEL_ID=9230
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.5:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1a_0-usb-0_1_5_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=HD_Camera_Manufacturer_USB_2.0_Camera
E: ID_TYPE=video
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=uvcvideo
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:0e0100:0e0200:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_V4L_CAPABILITIES=:capture:
E: ID_V4L_PRODUCT=USB 2.0 Camera: HD USB Camera
E: ID_V4L_VERSION=2
E: ID_VENDOR=HD_Camera_Manufacturer
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=HD\x20Camera\x20Manufacturer
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=05a3
E: MAJOR=81
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=video4linux
E: TAGS=:uaccess:seat:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=23692957
```

As you can see, the second value in **DEVLINKS** provides a hardware location that you can use to call your camera.

**Second Comment**

OpenCV has built in functions to do conversions on frames. Your method and the example I'll use are both in [this post](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-opencv-bgr-rgb-cvtcolor/). In order to look more into things, lets give this a try.

For Example -

The method of code you are using is fine:

```
# Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)

rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]
```

Try using this **example for problem two** if it does not work:

```
rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

**Conclusions**

I hope that this response helped. I don't think its a conversion problem but most likely a camera initialization issue. Try getting a more accurate camera feed location and this will provide you with a more robust way to call the camera. Have a nice day!

Comment: I almost forgot my question because pending project, pending not mean cancel so thanks for answer my question. Now I understand the problem, and don't worry I'm linux user too. I will try your answer. thanks, hope this will fix

Answer (score 1):

The main part is to test if the object is None as seen in the comment 'The error message says that video_capture.read() returned None'

```
video_capture.read()
```

If the type is none, just break out of the for loop as shown below.

```
for i in range(1,length-1):

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        print(type(frame))
        
        if frame is None:
            print('Noneeeee')
            break
```

A entire code sample is shown below. The reference for the entire code is -  https://expoleet.medium.com/flask-opencv-face-recognition-b9cbc3d1d280

```
import os 
import sys
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/root/backendOne/pyflaskone/upload'

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt','mp4'])
app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app, support_credentials=True)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
NEWPATH=""
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('request recieved....')
        
        image_file = request.files['video']
        print(image_file)
       
        filename = "aaa.mp4"
        
        image_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
       
        print('file savedd.....', filename)
        NEWPATH=videotest(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        if(NEWPATH == "Unknown"):
            flash('No matches for attendance')
        else:    
            flash('File successfully uploaded', NEWPATH)
            print(NEWPATH,'NEWPATH....')
            
           
        return {"status": "Success", "userName": NEWPATH}
        
    
    #else 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return """
        <!doctype html>
        <title>Upload new File</title>
        <h1>Upload new File</h1>
        <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <p><input type=file name=file>
            <input type=submit value=Upload>
        </form>
        <p>%s</p>
        """ % "<br>".join(os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],))


def videotest(filename):
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
    length = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    fps = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

    harmesh = face_recognition.load_image_file("harmesh.jpg")
    hfencoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(harmesh)[0]

    prateek = face_recognition.load_image_file("prateek.jpeg")
    pfencoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(prateek)[0]

    krishna = face_recognition.load_image_file("BusinessCards.jpg")
    kfencoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(krishna)[0]
    
    balaji = face_recognition.load_image_file("Balaji-Photo.jpg")
    bfencoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(balaji)[0]

    known_face_encodings = [
        hfencoding,
        pfencoding,
        kfencoding,
        bfencoding
    ]
    known_face_names = [
        "Harmesh",
        "Prateek",
        "Krrrr",
        "Balaji"
    ]
    name = "Unknown"
    width  = int(video_capture.get(3)) # float
    height = int(video_capture.get(4))

    for i in range(1,length-1):
        
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        print(type(frame))
        
        if frame is None:
            print('Noneeeee')
            break
        rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]    
        
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)
        for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        
            face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
            print(best_match_index)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
                print('if matchesss', name)
    
    video_capture.release()
    #out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print('final name', name)
    return name
    

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host ='0.0.0.0')
```